# Casting, structs and common initial sequence

Tags: c, pointers, casting, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

Given:

```
struct A {
    int i;
    char c;
    double d;

    int x;
    char y;
    double z;
};

struct B {
    int i;
    char c;
    double d;

    int x;
    long y;
    double z;
};

struct A *a = ...
```

as I understand it, this is okay because the field being accessed is part of the common initial sequence of the two structs:

```
((struct B *)a)->d = 1.2;
```

but this is not, because the differing `y` fields make `z` not part of the common initial sequence:

```
((struct B *)a)->z = 1.2;
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Common initial sequences only apply in `union`s. `struct A` and `struct B` are incompatible (regardless of what's in them) and members of one should not be accessed through a pointer to the other. It's a common mistake. Last time I checked certain popular codebases like libuv relied on this in structs, and the BSD socket API sort of makes people think it is OK, but according to the C standard people it isn't.

Comment: @PSkocik Aha. LLVM implements unions using code similar to the above, but that's just an implementation detail of LLVM, and as far as the C standard is concerned, to make the above correct, you would have to put A and B in a union?

Comment: @PSkocik POSIX guarantees that the aliasing the BSD socket API does is okay. However, on a compiler that requires some other black magic (such as a `union`), the system headers would need to do that.

Answer (score 4):

From the standard, 6.5.2.3 p5:

> One special guarantee is made in order to simplify the use of unions:
>   if a union contains several structures that share a common initial
>   sequence (see below), and if the union object currently contains one
>   of these structures, it is permitted to inspect the common initial
>   part of any of them **anywhere that a declaration of the complete type of
>   the union is visible**. Two structures share a common initial sequence
>   if corresponding members have compatible types (and, for bit-ﬁelds,
>   the same widths) for a sequence of one or more initial members.

So your first snippet is *almost* okay. The C standard only allows you to use the common initial sequence if a union involving them is visible at that point. Thus, adding `union Foo{ struct A; struct B; };` after the declarations of `A` and `B` should make your first snippet well-defined, *even if the structs you're examining aren't actually stored in such a union*. (Presumably this stricture is important because it allows the compiler to make more daring optimizations for structures you don't intend to alias.)

As th33lf said, your second snippet is UB, period.

Comment: Does the access need to be through the parent union type or will it work even if we use the child struct types and typecast between them?

Comment: @th33lf That is an interesting question. AFAICT, typecasting directly between the struct types and using the resultant pointer is UB, because the two struct types are not compatible (the only thing you can legally do with the result is convert it *back* to the original type). Nevertheless, I suspect that the semantics around converting to/from the union type implicitly force the result to be well-defined as long as the two struct types have the same alignment requirements.

Comment: Neither gcc nor clang care about whether a complete definition of the union type is visible.  Even given a construct like `(someUnion->arrayOfStructure1+index1)->member`, they won't recognize the possibility of interaction with `(someUnion->arrayOfStructure2+index2)->member`.

Comment: @th33lf: I think the authors of the Standard intended that quality implementations should support common constructs involving casting between structure types, but not necessarily all conceivable corner cases involving such casts, at least in contexts where the *complete union type definition* is visible.  They didn't explicitly mandate that, but instead treated it as a quality-of-implementation issue along with some more general issues surrounding access types.  The `-fstrict-aliasing` dialect of clang and gcc, however, makes no effort to support anything beyond the lowest-quality semantics.

Comment: @supercat The paragraph of the Standard that you cite in your answer does in fact make such guarantees. The example you gave contains a different but related form of UB: the code decays the arrays into a `struct s1*` and a `struct s2*`, which are not allowed to alias each other even if they both point to a union member.

Comment: @Davislor: It would have been considered obvious to pretty much everyone in 1989 that a quality compiler that can see that a pointer is formed by taking the address of a union member should recognize that an access using the resulting pointer *is* an access to the parent union object, at least in contexts where the derivation is visible and all use of the resulting pointer occurs before any other actions involving the parent object.  The notion that the anyone seeking to write a quality compiler would do otherwise would have been considered absurd.

Comment: @supercat Type-punning through unions has always worked (or every program that used BSD sockets would break). Strict aliasing is relatively newer. Back in the ’90s, the C standards committee got a bit envious about the optimizations Fortran compilers could perform.

Comment: @Davislor: The authors of the Standard didn't put optimization ahead of "Don't prevent the programmer from doing what needs to be done".  Instead, they figured that the marketplace would know more than the Committee about what needed to be done and support it, whether the Standard mandated it or not.  The "billion dollar mistake" is failing to include a footnote: "Of course, quality compilers shouldn't use this section as an excuse to be obtuse".  For a compiler to apply the rule as shown in the rationale would have been widely recognized as reasonable; to apply it as gcc does, absurd.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, it is currently undefined behaviour on all platforms, as per the strict aliasing rules. If you wrap both the structs in a common union, your first example might work as intended. However, your second example becomes implementation dependent - it might work on platforms that enforce an alignment equal to or greater than the size of long, but not on others.

```
union C 
{
    struct A a;
    struct B b;
};

C *c;
c->a.d = 1.2; // Valid
c->b.d = 1.5; // Valid and sets the value of a.d as well
c->b.z = 1.2; // Valid but may not set the value of a.z as expected
```

Answer (score 2):

The way N1570 6.5p7 is written makes no allowance for any operation that would access a struct or union using an lvalue of non-character member type (it does allow a member of a struct or union to be accessed using an arbitrary lvalue of an enclosing struct or union type, but not the reverse).  Thus, given something like:

```
struct blob { int size; int *dat; };

void clear_blob(blob *p)
{
  for (int i=0; i < p->size; i++)
    p->dat[i] = 0;
}
```

the Standard avoids (IMHO deliberately, though I don't think all members of the Committee noticed this) requiring that a compiler allow for the possibility that `p->dat` might hold the address of `p->size` while `p->size` holds a value of 2 or greater.  In that case, the store would cause `size` to hold zero, which would in turn cause the loop to exit after its first iteration rather than running for `size` iterations.

Of course, the language would be largely useless if implementations could not be relied upon to allow the stored values of structures and unions to be accessed using lvalues of member types in at least some circumstances, but the Committee left the question of exactly what those circumstances should be as a quality-of-implementation issue, outside the Standard's jurisdiction, expecting that people designing compilers for kinds of customers (number-crunchers, systems programmers, etc.) would no more than the committee about what their particular customers would need, and saw no need to mandate that compilers support constructs that compiler writers would have had to be deliberately obtuse to ignore.

Neither clang nor gcc will reliably support code which takes the address of a union member and uses the pointer to access an object of that type except when using `-fno-strict-aliasing` mode.  Even given something like:

```
struct s1 {int x;};
struct s2 {int x;};
union { struct s1 v1[10]; struct s2 v2[10];} uarr;
int test(int i, int j)
{
    if ((uarr.v1+i)->x)
        (uarr.v2+j)->x = 0;
    return (uarr.v1+i)->x;
}
```

they won't recognize that the access to `(uarr.v2+j)->x` might interact with `(uarr.v1+i)->x`.  The ability to handle such code, however, is not required for conformance but is merely a quality-of-implementation issue.  While present versions of clang and gcc happen to support similar code using the `[]` operator, the Standard does not mandate the behavior of any expression of the form `E1[E2]` operator in any cases where it would not be equivalent to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`--a form which clang and gcc do not support.

Comment: That is sad. We're practically telling the compiler that s1 & s2 alias using the 'union' keyword! At least wherever accesses are through a union type, the standard should have clearly mandated that aliasing be accounted for in all cases.

Comment: @th33lf: Better yet would have been for the Committee to acknowledge *within the Standard* that in many cases the choice of how to behave when the Standard imposes no requirements should be regarded as a Quality of Implementation issue outside the Committee's jurisdiction, and that failure to mandate the behavior of certain constructs was in no way intended to demean them.  Both concepts are clearly stated in the Rationale, but the authors of gcc and clang don't care about that.

Comment: Change `(uarr.v1+i)->x` to `uarr.v1[i].x` and `(uarr.v2+j)->x` to `uarr.v2[j].x`, and [both gcc 9.1](https://godbolt.org/) and [clang 8.0.0](https://godbolt.org/z/NNY0oB) correctly notice the potential aliasing, as required by the standard. The example only breaks because the code decays the arrays into pointers to `s1` and `s2`, which then violate the strict-aliasing rules.

Comment: You understate what guarantees the Standard makes. The paragraph you cite explicitly states that access through “an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union)” is legal, where those aforementioned types include all compatible types.

Comment: @Davislor: According to the Standard, "The definition of the subscript operator []
    is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2)))".  Exact words.  Therefore, in cases where `*((E1)+(E2))` would invoke UB, `E1[E2]` would do likewise.  The only way in which the clang/gcc behavior would make sense would be if support for such constructs when using the `[]` operator is a Quality of Implementation issue, and the authors of the Standard assumed implementations would support some forms of access beyond those mandated by the Standard, including but not necessarily limited to the `[]` form.

Comment: @supercat You make a strong case that gcc and clang are not strictly conforming. The Standard, on the other hand, does specifically mention access through aggregate types such as arrays and structs as legal.

Comment: @Davislor: For every version of clang and gcc, I'm pretty sure one could formulate at least one text file which would exercise all the translation limits given in N1570 5.2.4.1, and which would be processed in a manner consistent with the Standard.  The Standard does not require that implementations be able to process any other programs meaningfully.  Personally, I wish the Standard would recognize the existence of a dialect with clang/gcc aliasing rules, which would eliminate any requirement for implementations to handle some of the pesky corner cases in the present Standard, ...

Comment: ...as well as a dialect that would recognize that the notion of aliasing is only applicable in cases where two references to an object are used within some context, and they are not both based, within that context, upon the same object or members of the same array, or where an object that is guarded by a "restrict" pointer is accessed within the lifetime of that pointer via means not based upon it.

Comment: @supercat I respectfully disagree. In any case, I hope you’ll change your line about “makes no allowance for any operation that would access a struct or union using an lvalue of non-character member type.” That is inaccurate. The very paragraph you refer to does specifically state that such access is legal.

Comment: @Davislor: The rules allow access to an aggregate member object via means of an object of an enclosing aggregate's type, but they do *not* list member types as being among those suitable for accessing aggregate.  If a compiler treats any use of `.` or `->` on an lvalue of type T as an indication to refrain from reordering any later operations on T's member types before the use of the result from `.` or `->` operation, that would eliminate the need for the compiler to treat arbitrary lvalues of member type as capable of affecting the values of aggregates.  Fancier compilers may be...

Comment: ...more selective about reordering barriers in cases where they can see everything that is done with the derived pointers or lvalues, and it would be hard to write rules that would sensibly but unambiguously describe every possible optimization scenario as allowed or forbidden.  Do you think the authors of the Standard wanted to forbid the first optimization described in my answer?

Comment: @supercat Incorrect. It lists “an aggregate  or  union  type  that  includes  one  of  the  aforementioned  types  **among  its members**” (6.5, paragraph 7, emphasis added.)

Comment: @Davislor: Correct.  That would allow an object of type `unsigned` to be an accessed by an lvalue of type `struct s1` [from the example], because `struct s1` includes `int` among its members, and `int` is compatible with `unsigned`.  For a union of `uarr`'s type, however, the only types listed in 6.5p7 that would be applicable would be qualified or unqualified versions of that type, or aggregates *containing* a union of that type.

Comment: @supercat Scroll up and you’ll see that the very next words following that are, “includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union)”.

Comment: @Davislor: The possessive "its" refers to the lvalue *used for access*, while the "aforementioned types" are those applicable to the pre-existing object whose storage is being accessed.  Likewise, the terms "sub-aggregate or contained union" refer to sub-aggregates or contained unions of the lvalue used for access.

Comment: @supercat The “aforementioned types” are those mentioned previously in the paragraph. I think anyone reading this far has enough information to read the Standard for themselves and make up their own minds. I hope you’ll edit your answer to remove the inaccuracy.

Comment: @Davislor: The "aforementioned types" are "a type compatible with the effective type of the object (ATCWTETOTO)", "a qualified version of ATCWTETOTO", "a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to ATCWTETOTO", and "a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of ATCWTETOTO".  Why do you think should compilers should be required to accommodate the possibility that structs or unions might be accessed by pointers or lvalues of member type that are not visibly derived from pointers or lvalues of the struct or union type?

Comment: @Davislor: Is there anything in the Standard that would distinguish between `uarr.v2[j].x = 0;`, `(*(uarr.v2+j)).x = 0;`, or `do{struct s2 *p2 = uarr.v2+j; (*p).x=0;} while(0);`?  If not, what would distinguish situations where a `struct p2*` may be used to access the stored value of `uarr` and those where it may not?

Comment: @supercat That’s a good question, but unfortunately, I don’t have time to continue this discussion right now. Thanks for the excellent responses!

Comment: @supercat I think the gcc or clang devs would have to argue that the type-punning through the union isn’t strictly required to work either. Otherwise, their compilers aren’t conforming. ICC 9.1 correctly detects the potential aliasing.

Comment: @Davislor: For the clang/gcc devs to argue that `someUnion.array[index]` isn't required to work would require acknowledging that either (1) the Standard requires that implementations accept constructs that aren't intended to actually be usable, or (2) the failure of the Standard to mandate that implementations support a construct usefully does not imply a judgment that *quality* implementations shouldn't be expected to make reasonable effort to do so anyway in cases that would help programmers do what needs to be done.  Of course, if the goal is merely to be "conforming", that wouldn't matter.